# No matching function for call to ‘ros::NodeHandle::param’

Tags: ros, build

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have the following line of C++ code:

```
private_nh_.param("max_desired_publish_freq", max_desired_publish_freq_, double(5.0));
```

and the type of the variable `max_desired_publish_freq_` is `double_t`.

This builds fine on an x86_64 machine (my machine) as well as on the 64 bit ROS build jobs, but for some reason, it fails on i386 builds with the following error:

```
16:08:17 /tmp/binarydeb/ros-indigo-rail-object-detector-1.0.2/src/rail_object_detector/detector.cpp: In member function ‘bool rail_object_detector::Detector::start()’:
16:08:17 /tmp/binarydeb/ros-indigo-rail-object-detector-1.0.2/src/rail_object_detector/detector.cpp:56:32: error: no matching function for call to ‘ros::NodeHandle::param(const char [25], double_t&, double)’
16:08:17                      double(5.0));
16:08:17                                 ^
16:08:17 /tmp/binarydeb/ros-indigo-rail-object-detector-1.0.2/src/rail_object_detector/detector.cpp:56:32: note: candidates are:
16:08:17 In file included from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:45:0,
16:08:17                  from /tmp/binarydeb/ros-indigo-rail-object-detector-1.0.2/include/rail_object_detector/detector.h:17,
16:08:17                  from /tmp/binarydeb/ros-indigo-rail-object-detector-1.0.2/src/rail_object_detector/detector.cpp:5:
16:08:17 /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:2039:8: note: template<class T> void ros::NodeHandle::param(const string&, T&, const T&) const
16:08:17    void param(const std::string& param_name, T& param_val, const T& default_val) const
16:08:17         ^
16:08:17 /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:2039:8: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
16:08:17 /tmp/binarydeb/ros-indigo-rail-object-detector-1.0.2/src/rail_object_detector/detector.cpp:56:32: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘const T’ (‘long double’ and ‘double’)
16:08:17                      double(5.0));
16:08:17                                 ^
16:08:17 In file included from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:45:0,
16:08:17                  from /tmp/binarydeb/ros-indigo-rail-object-detector-1.0.2/include/rail_object_detector/detector.h:17,
16:08:17                  from /tmp/binarydeb/ros-indigo-rail-object-detector-1.0.2/src/rail_object_detector/detector.cpp:5:
16:08:17 /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:2071:5: note: template<class T> T ros::NodeHandle::param(const string&, const T&)
16:08:17    T param(const std::string& param_name, const T& default_val)
16:08:17      ^
16:08:17 /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:2071:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
16:08:17 /tmp/binarydeb/ros-indigo-rail-object-detector-1.0.2/src/rail_object_detector/detector.cpp:56:32: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 3 provided
16:08:17                      double(5.0));
```

This seems to indicate that the function for getting parameters from the parameter server with default values in the code does not exist in the 32-bit version of ROS; but that seems unlikely.

Any help figuring out what's really going on here would be greatly appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253797/no-matching-function-for-call-to-%E2%80%98ros::nodehandle::param%E2%80%99/) by [banerjs](https://answers.ros.org/users/29163/banerjs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2017-02-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The answer is in the error output:

```
16:08:17 /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/node_handle.h:2039:8: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
16:08:17 /tmp/binarydeb/ros-indigo-rail-object-detector-1.0.2/src/rail_object_detector/detector.cpp:56:32: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘const T’ (‘long double’ and ‘double’)
16:08:17                      double(5.0));
16:08:17                                 ^
```

Both `long double` and `double` are valid types; evidently, the compiler you're using can't disambiguate them.

This is outside my realm of knowledge; I'm not sure if people run into this often or if there's a typical fix. But it seems to me that you should be able to explicitly declare and initialize a typed variable on the line before and use that:

```
double x=5.0;
private_nh_.param("max_desired_publish_freq", max_desired_publish_freq_, x);
```

---

Originally posted by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) with karma: 1470 on 2017-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [banerjs](https://answers.ros.org/users/29163/banerjs/) on 2017-02-05**:
Of course! I didn't notice that line with long double. `double_t` must be parsed as a `long double` on 32-bit. Thanks!